# Not allow the adding components to resize a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a parent JPanel *parentPanel* layed out with GridBagLayout. Inside these panel I have another 3 child `JPanels("childPanel1", "childPanel2", "childPanel3")` like this:

```
 _____ _____
|     | 2   |
|  1  |_____|
|     | 3   |
|_____|_____|
```

I added the panelParent in a fixed size JFrame with BorderLayout.CENTER and I want the frame to stay fixed(not resizable), 600 x 400. 
The widths of the child panels are all equal and I want them *to remain equal.*
For the child panels I used GridBagLayout as well.
I arranged components inside childPanel1, all fine the widths still equal.

The problem: when I start to add components into childPanel2, it resizes itself and the other 2 childPanels. *The child panels widths are no more equal.* It becomes something like this:

```
 ____ ______
|    |  2   |
|  1 |______|
|    |  3   |
|____|______|
```

I having two questions,

1. How can I keep the child panels not resizeable, after I add
   components into them, all having the same width?
2. The automatic resize of the panel has to do with the JPanel, parent
   layout, child layout or component properties?

I'm just starting to get my head around Swing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (but likely not the best) way would probably be to just override the `getPreferredSize` method of every child `JPanel`:

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public Example() {

        JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        parentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        parentPanel.add(createChildPanel(1), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        parentPanel.add(createChildPanel(2), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        parentPanel.add(createChildPanel(3), gbc);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(parentPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createChildPanel(int number) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(150, 150);
            }
        };

        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

        JButton addButton = new JButton("+");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                addPanel.add(new JLabel("Label"));
                addPanel.revalidate();
                addPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("-");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (addPanel.getComponentCount() > 0) {
                    addPanel.remove(addPanel.getComponent(addPanel.getComponentCount() - 1));
                    addPanel.revalidate();
                    addPanel.repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(number));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(addPanel);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

}
```